# How to exclude opencv compilation from Yocto image?

Tags: opencv, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm compiling image fsl-image-validation-imx. I have to compile opencv. How to exclude it from image compilation.

Comment: What do you mean by exclude? Do you wish to have another layer for opencv like meta-opencv?

Comment: When i input command 'bitbake fsl-image-validation-imx', opencv is starting building. I want to avoid compiling of opencv.

Comment: Should I add layer or edit local.conf?

Comment: You will have to do both, otherwise opencv is generally present in meta-python or meta-openembedded. So to just access this recipe and get it compiled and added up using bitbake, add opencv in local.conf